# How to replace specific row using sed or awk based with run command

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a csv file looks like this:

```
site1.com,aaa,bbb,ccc
site2.com,qqq
site3.com,rrr,uuu,ppp
site4.com
site5.com,ddd,sss
```

I want to replace rows (lines) where the fourth column is empty.
 and I want to manipulate said rows by running a command on them.
For example, with `awk`:

```
awk -F, '$4=="" {system("$1,cmd1 $1")}' test.csv
```

I then want to export as follows (output1 is output from cmd1 command):

```
site1.com,aaa,bbb,ccc
site2.com,output1
site3.com,rrr,uuu,ppp
site4.com,output1
site5.com,output1
```

Comment: `cmd1` should be run with the first field as argument, right?

Comment: I ignore my own advice occasionally but I strongly advise using a proper table editing tool here instead of awk (my own weapon of choice is R, but there are others, such as [`csvtool`](http://colin.maudry.com/csvtool-manual-page/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{ if ( $4 == "" ){printf "%s,",$1 ; system(CMD) ;}else {print $0}}' test.csv
```

If the fourth filed is empty print the first field with the output of the command, else print the hole line.

But be aware of the output of the command how it will print

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -F, -v q=\' '
  function shellquote(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    return q s q
  }
  $4 == "" {
    printf "%s,", $1
    system("cmd " shellquote($1))
    next
  }
  {print}'
```

The `shellquote` part is important. Consider the case of a value of `$1` like `;reboot` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```
awk -v output1="$(cmd1)" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF&&NF<4{print $1,output1}1' file
```

The option `-v` set the variable `output1` as the result of the shell command `cmd1`.

The statement `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` is setting the delimiter to the comma.

If the line is not empty and the number of fields is lower than 4, replace the line.

At last, the `1` triggers the default statement in `awk`: print the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

may be this post helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646819/how-can-i-pass-variables-from-awk-to-a-shell-command

```
$ cat input.txt
a,b,c,d
a,b
a,b,c,d
a,b,c
a,b,c,d


$ awk -F, 'NF<4{cmd="echo output1";while(cmd|getline line){printf("%s,%s\n",$0,line)};close(cmd);next}1' input.txt
a,b,c,d
a,b,output1
a,b,c,d
a,b,c,output1
a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -rn '
/\S+,\S+,\S+,\S+/{p;b}      # if all four columns exist, print and branch to end
s/^([^,]+).*/\1/            # else extract first column
h                           # hold
s/.*/echo output &/e        # exeute external command echo with first column as argument
G                           # append previous hold value
s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2,\1/         # arrange position
p' file                     # print result
```