# How to replace rows that nth to mth columns from them are empty using sed or awk based with run command

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a csv file looks like this:

```
site1.com,aaa,bbb,ccc
site2.com,qqq
site3.com,rrr,uuu,ppp
site4.com,ddd,sss
site5.com,www,rrr,yyy,uuu
site6.com,,,,ttt,,,,
site7.com,,,uuuu,,,,ppp,
site8.com,,,,ggg,zzz
```

I want to replace rows (lines) where the nth to mth (2th to 4th) columns are empty. and I want to manipulate said rows by running a command on them. For example, with awk:

```
awk -F, '$n-$m=="" {printf "%s,",$1 ; system(cmd1) ;}else {print $0}' test.csv
awk -F, '$2-$4=="" {printf "%s,",$1 ; system(cmd1) ;}else {print $0}' test.csv
```

I then want to export as follows (output1 is output from cmd1 command):

```
site1.com,aaa,bbb,ccc
site2.com,qqq
site3.com,rrr,uuu,ppp
site4.com,ddd,sss
site5.com,www,rrr,yyy,uuu
site6.com,output1
site7.com,,,uuuu,,,,ppp,
site8.com,output1
```

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify.i) Should rows with <N fields be left alone? ii) Why is `site7.com` left unchanged in your example? Fields 2-4 are blank there. Should there be at least N+1 fields?

Comment: sorry you are right

Comment: OK, and what is `system("$1,cmd1 $1")` supposed to be? That syntax doesn't make sense. The `system()` call returns the exit status of the command. Is that what you want? What is the `$1,cmd1 $1` supposed to be?

Comment: $1 is first column. ok i modify. actually cmd1 is a sample shell command or calling function. for example <echo test>

Comment: Yes, but the `system()` function of `awk` returns the *exit status* and not the command's output. Is that what you want? Or do you want the output of the command? Does it *need* to be a system call? Can't you just do it in `awk` directly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51116/discussion-between-terdon-and-alrz).

Comment: please visit This question. Previously I asked this question. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330004/how-to-replace-specific-row-using-sed-or-awk-based-with-run-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want 3 columns, you can do this with:

```
awk -F, '{
            if($2=="" && $3==$2 && $3==$4){
                printf "%s,",$1; 
                system("CMD")
            }
            else{print}
          }' test.csv
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but this answer for 2th and 3th and 4th columns. If I want to do for 2th to end columns. how to do ?

Comment: @alrz did you try it?

Comment: yes. Works properly. thanks. If possible I want to do for 2th to end columns. for csv file with a lot columns